# What's the meaning of "joint winner"?

Tags: meaning

I looked it up on Google and in my English dictionary but cannot find out its meaning. The context is [this page](http://pascallin.ecs.soton.ac.uk/challenges/VOC/voc2011/workshop/index.html).

> As usual the crime stories have split our judges so, as with last years Fish-Knife Award, we have **joint winners** of the Crime section of the Criminally-Short Short Histories Award.

Comment: Did you mean *joint winner*?

Comment: We will need some context.

Comment: Could be even '*joint whiner*', for that matter.

Comment: General Reference: sense 14 at http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/joint

Comment: GR. Voting to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a context, I'd say it means that there were at least two **winners** (it can't be "winer", but it could be "whiner" or "whinger"). A and B. Maybe A bought 100 lottery tickets and B paid for 50, and one of them was the winning ticket. The sentence is about A, one of the winners, and it mentions the other winner, B, who wasn't interviewed.

You can look up the adjective *joint* in a dictionary and learn that it means "shared by or affecting two or more " and *joint venture* and discover that it means "With individuals, when two or more persons come together to form a temporary partnership for the purpose of carrying out a particular project, such partnership can also be called a joint venture where the parties are 'co-venturers'." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_venture

But I'm just guessing. Always provide a context for such questions. Without a context, some things are just plain meaningless.

Comment: The context is this page http://pascallin.ecs.soton.ac.uk/challenges/VOC/voc2011/workshop/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the context. Two different and apparently unrelated sets of researchers shared first prize. Normally, contests have one first-place winner. Sometimes the judges can't decide on one and want two winners: joint winners who didn't work together, but both deserve first prize.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the judges were unable to choose between the two (*) best competitors, and awarded first place to both of them.

Therefore, those two best competitors are described as "joint first", "joint winners", etc.

---

(*) there could be two *or more* joint winners, it doesn't really affect the sense.

Answer (score -2):

'Joint Winner': means that two people have won together.

Photofinish

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photo_finish

> A photo finish occurs in a sporting race when multiple competitors cross the finishing line at nearly the same time. As the naked eye may not be able to discriminate between which of the competitors crossed the line first, a photo or video taken at the finish line may be used for a more accurate check.

Comment: *Photo finish* is not relevant to *joint winner*.

Comment: Yes it is, it is about two people winning together - a photofinish.

Comment: Check back your reference. Photo finish is used to **decide** the winner among several -- **not** to award as joint winners.

Comment: @RobinMichael: Photo finish means that to the naked eye it appears as if two or more horses (usually) crossed the finish line at the same time, but after looking at the photo of the finish, one of those horses will have crossed the line before the other(s) and will be declared "the winner by a nose".

Comment: Of course I know what photofinish means.